# What is the difference between the Comprehension scheme an Replacemnt scheme?

Tags: set-theory, axioms

I am currently studying ZFC axioms and having trouble understanding the difference between the comprehension scheme and the replacement scheme. Here's what I understand about the two schemes so far.
The comprehension scheme allows us to create a new set whose elements are members of a given set obeying some property and the replacement scheme let us create a new set which is the image of an existing set under a function.
So both the scheme just creates a new set with some elements from already existing set according to some property P.

Answer (score 3):

Comprehension requires that the elements already be part of a set.  You are making a subset from the elements that have the property of interest.  Replacement allows the elements of the new set to come from anywhere as the range of the function may not be known to be a set.  If I apply comprehension to $\Bbb N$ I can get any subset of the naturals that I can describe.  If I apply replacement to $\Bbb N$ I can get any countable set that I can describe.

Comment: If replacement allowed the elements to come from anywhere would it not be the Russell's paradox

Comment: No, you still can't construct a set of all sets not members of themselves.

Comment: I am trying to understand this but I don't cant make sense of it. Could you please explain it a bit more

Comment: For example, if you start from $\Bbb N$, with comprehension you can get set of naturals.  You could define a function $0 \to \Bbb N, 1 \to P(\Bbb N), 2 \to P(P(\Bbb N)), \ldots$ and use that function and replacement to get $\{\Bbb N, P(\Bbb N), P(P(\Bbb N)), \ldots\}$.  You could get there in a bunch of steps of power set applied to $\Bbb N$ followed by comprehension, but replacement can be applied to $\Bbb N$

Comment: @RossMillikan Not sure if this is what you're claiming in the last sentence of your last comment, but I don't think you can show that the set $\{\mathbb N, P(\mathbb N), P(P(\mathbb N)),\ldots\}$ exists without replacement.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen:  I was thinking that you could get each of the elements from power set, which you can, then sort out this set by comprehension.   It now seems to me you can't get the whole set that way.

Comment: Thank you very much